AdminJS not working due to null origin caused by CORS error when using helmet
src/app.ts
const app = express();

app.use(rTracer.expressMiddleware());
app.use(requestLogger);

app.use(helmet());

app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: getAllowedOrigins,
  }),
);


src/cors.ts
import { NODE_ENV } from 'common/constants';

export function getAllowedOrigins(
  origin: string | undefined,
  callback: Function,
) {
  let allowedOrigins: string[] = [];
  if (NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    allowedOrigins = [
      'http://localhost:3000',
      'http://localhost:8000',
      'http://localhost:34273',
    ];
  } else if (NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:3000'];
  } else if (NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    allowedOrigins = ['https://www.somewebsite.com', 'https://somewebsite.com'];
  }
  if (!origin || allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
    return callback(null, true);
  } else {
    return callback(new Error(origin + ' not allowed by CORS'));
  }
}



I am having a lot of trouble with AdminJS + CORS + Helmet combination. I am trying many things and none of them seems to work
Basically the admin panel simply won't load unless I either remove CORS or remove Helmet
I can see the login page
But as soon as I login, I get this CORS error
Look at the request and response headers if you need
I suspect this happens because origin = null in the above getAllowedOrigins CORS callback function

What have I tried
Don't use helmet middleware at all but use CORS as above

Still get the error after removing helmet

Use helmet but remove CORS

Now I get a blank page with some errors
The errors seem to do something with content security policy
Did some digging and found out a guy with the same issue
Seems like a CSP error, lets try that recommended solution shall we?

src/app.ts
const app = express();

app.use(rTracer.expressMiddleware());
app.use(requestLogger);

app.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      directives: {
        defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
        scriptSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "'unsafe-eval'"],
        styleSrc: ["'self'", 'https:', "'unsafe-inline'"],
        baseUri: ["'self'"],
        fontSrc: ["'self'", 'https:', 'data:'],
      },
    },
  }),
);



Modified my app.ts as per the guy s solution, lets try that again
Ok admin panel seems to work now
But I cannot use this express server without CORS because my production app runs frontend on a separate domain

Add CORS back after helmet
src/app.ts
const app = express();

app.use(rTracer.expressMiddleware());
app.use(requestLogger);

app.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      directives: {
        defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
        scriptSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "'unsafe-eval'"],
        styleSrc: ["'self'", 'https:', "'unsafe-inline'"],
        baseUri: ["'self'"],
        fontSrc: ["'self'", 'https:', 'data:'],
      },
    },
  }),
);

app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: getAllowedOrigins,
  }),
);


Oh boy, we are back to the same error again
Maybe it has something to do with the order of the middleware?
Let me try adding CORS first and then helmet

Add CORS before helmet
src/app.ts
const app = express();

app.use(rTracer.expressMiddleware());
app.use(requestLogger);

app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: getAllowedOrigins,
  }),
);

app.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      directives: {
        defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
        scriptSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "'unsafe-eval'"],
        styleSrc: ["'self'", 'https:', "'unsafe-inline'"],
        baseUri: ["'self'"],
        fontSrc: ["'self'", 'https:', 'data:'],
      },
    },
  }),
);



Oh man, we are back to the same error again
I cannot remove CORS because my production backend and frontend run on separate domains but how do I make this admin panel work with CORS?

Edit 1
const app = express();

app.use(rTracer.expressMiddleware());
app.use(requestLogger);

app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: getAllowedOrigins,
  }),
);

app.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: false,
    crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false,
    crossOriginOpenerPolicy: false,
    crossOriginResourcePolicy: false,
    originAgentCluster: false,
    referrerPolicy: false,
    strictTransportSecurity: false,
    xContentTypeOptions: false,
    xDnsPrefetchControl: false,
    xDownloadOptions: false,
    xFrameOptions: false,
    xPermittedCrossDomainPolicies: false,
    xXssProtection: false,
  }),
);


I disabled all the options and it works so obviously there is some setting in helmet that is interfering with adminJS. Looking into it


const app = express();

app.use(rTracer.expressMiddleware());
app.use(requestLogger);

app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: getAllowedOrigins,
  }),
);

// https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/adminjs/issues/607#issuecomment-693621747
app.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      directives: {
        defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
        scriptSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "'unsafe-eval'"],
        styleSrc: ["'self'", 'https:', "'unsafe-inline'"],
        baseUri: ["'self'"],
        fontSrc: ["'self'", 'https:', 'data:'],
        imgSrc: [
          "'self'",
          'data:',
          'https://imagine.ai',
          'https://www.imagine.ai',
        ],
      },
    },
    referrerPolicy: {
      policy: 'same-origin',
    },
  }),
);

This works but I have no idea why
